# what is this weird code notation mean

Tags: objective-c

what's this line mean when using the second NSDictionay beside the message body:

`NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *) [self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.content` is a property of type `NSArray` (I guess!)

This line returns you the Object (which seams to be a `NSDictionary`) at Index `indexPath.row`. `(NSDictionary*)` casts the object to `NSDictionary`.

Comment: the returned object is a dictionary, but why it's been casted to a dictionary ?

Comment: because the compiler doesn't know which type is stored in the array

Comment: the rows are predefined dictionaries, so it knows what datatype is stored in that array!

Comment: The cast is completely unnecessary. It will convert `id` to `NSDictionary *` without a cast.

Answer (score 3):

`(NSDictionary *)` a type cast. It tells the compiler to assume that the object returned by the `objectAtIndex:` method is of the type `NSDictionary *` even though the return type of the method is different.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *cast*, as in C.

In your case, "self.content" seems to be an NSArray. So [self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] would be an NSObject. Except that here, for some reason, you *know* it's an NSDictionary. So you explicitly cast it in order to avoid a compiler warning (that would tell you "hey, you're assigning an NSObject to an NSDictionary variable)

Comment: `objectAtIndex:` returns `id` type not `NSObject *` type.

Comment: Oh, indeed, you're right. It should be an NSObject though, as objects added to an NSArray are retained and released, and therefore should be NSObjects.

Comment: It also should be noted that I don't think assigning an id to a variable of a given type would cause a warning.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be NSObject, because if it is NSObject then you wouldn't be able to chain method calls together, for example `[[array objectAtIndex:4] integerValue]` would not work because `integerValue` is not a method of `NSObject`, so the compiler would emit a warning.