# What does (anObject *) do before a statement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is this weird code notation mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778022/what-is-this-weird-code-notation-mean)

I have previously asked this question...

[Understanding memory management in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455797/understanding-memory-management-in-ios/9464958#9464958)

The one thing that that line of questioning didnt teach me is what does the `(NSArray *)` do in the following statement:

```
NSArray *myArray = (NSArray *)[someNSSet allObjects];
```

Why isnt it just:

```
NSArray *myArray = [someNSSet allObjects];
```

or put another way, how do the two statements differ in what they do? At the moment I dont understand the `(NSArray *)` bit so I just ignore it and to me they look the same!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typecast, which says "convert the return value to this type"†. It's pointless in Objective-C since `id` converts to and from any other object pointer type, but some other languages require a lot more casts, so some people do it out of habit, and others just do it because they really, *really* like explicitness.

I would generally advise against this, because on the rare occasion that you are doing something wrong (e.g. the method returns an `NSString*` and you're assigning it to an `NSArray*`), this will suppress the compiler's warning. And as noted above, if the method does return a compatible type, you don't need to do this. So doing this blindly can only hurt you in Objective-C.

<sup>† Note about casting: When you cast pointers, which includes all Objective-C object types, you don't actually change the type of the thing that the pointer references, only the pointer itself. So you can't change one type of object into another this way. If you cast an `NSString*` to an `NSDictionary*`, the object is still an NSString — you've just lied to the compiler about it, so it won't warn you when you try to call `allKeys`, and instead your program will just blow up at runtime.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It's a typecast statement. In cases of simple assignment it's extraneous - Objective C lets you assign a typeless object ref (`id`) to any typed variable. But people write them anyway, out of C/C++ inertia.

Sometimes it's required. For example:

```
NSString *s = [(UILabel*)[myView viewWithTag:100] text];
```

Here, if not for the typecast, you'd get a compiler warning that `UIView*` might not support `[text]`.

Answer (score 1):

`(NSArray *)` is a cast to an `NSArray *` However it's not needed since the `allObjects` method returns an `NSArray *` .

Answer (score 0):

It's a type cast. In the above case it is not necessary since `[someNSSet allObjects];` returns and `NSArray*` anyways, but you need it wherever you need to specify the type of object (usually from an `id`) so the compiler knows what method invocation to actually generate.

Answer (score 0):

in this case..it won't matter much..since you are assigning it to a array..

but take a case..where you assign IBActions.to button like this

```
- (IBAction) clickedButton:(id) sender
```

now in this function you want to set button alpha to zero..

you know that your button will be the sender...since you have done the IBaction connection to that..

but if you use

```
 sender.alpha = 0 ;
```

although it will work since it is true that it is button.. 
but for reading it ain't the best..and the compiler won't even complain even if you sent a method like `intvalue` to it..since it is id..

so you type case it to `(UIbutton *) sender`..to make the compiler understand it as a button and perform its working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you completely misunderstand pointers and types. I've been there. And after I read C for dummies or smthng (esp. pointers part) I understand it. It's basics, and you have to know C. The answer is: it is typecast.

Comment: Wow that's harsh......but fair! - I have never done C. Diving straight in to Objective-C!